# Multioutput-multiclass Machine Learning in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, decision-tree

I have been researching and am struggling to find the best method to tackle this problem I have. I have a training dataset and a test dataset. The test dataset is missing two feature columns that the training dataset has (Channel and Sector - both are composed of 4 classes).

I've built a decision tree on the data, however I can only train on either Channel or Sector with it, when I need to be able to train on both.

Can anyone give me a recommendation for implementing multiclass multioutput machine learning in python?

```
import os
import subprocess

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz

def getPath(thisFile):
    if os.path.exists(thisFile):
        df = pd.read_csv(thisFile, header=0)
    else:
        return
    return df

def visualize_tree(tree, feature_names):

    with open("dt.dot", 'w') as f:
        export_graphviz(tree, out_file=f,
                        feature_names=feature_names)

    command = ["dot", "-Tpng", "dt.dot", "-o", "dt.png"]
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(command)
    except:
        exit("Could not run dot, ie graphviz, to "
             "produce visualization")

data = np.loadtxt("newTrain2.csv", delimiter=',')
X = data[:, 1:4]
quantity = data[:, 2]
for i in range(len(quantity)):
    if quantity[i] < 30:
        quantity[i] = 1
    if quantity[i] >= 25 and quantity[i] < 75:
        quantity[i] = 2
    if quantity[i] >= 75 and quantity[i] < 250:
        quantity[i] = 3
    if quantity[i] > 250:
        quantity[i] = 4
revenue = data[:, 3]
for i in range(len(revenue)):
    if revenue[i] < 1000:
        revenue[i] = 1
    if revenue[i] >= 1000 and revenue[i] < 4000:
        revenue[i] = 2
    if revenue[i] >= 4000 and revenue[i] < 10000:
        revenue[i] = 3
    if revenue[i] > 10000:
        revenue[i] = 4
X[:, 1] = quantity
X[:, 2] = revenue



targets = data[:,4]

thisTree = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=30, random_state=99)
thisTree.fit(X, targets)
visualize_tree(thisTree, ["product", "quantity", "revenue"])
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to transform the two missing columns in only one, combining both classes. If each column has 4 different classes, the merged column would have 4 * 4 = 16 classes.

Comment: I ended up doing this, but I'm sure there are better methods